# Reconnecting to an existing SignalR (.NET CORE) socket with Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, .net-core, websocket, signalr

In my project, I need to reconnect to a SignalR Web Socket if the internet connection is lost.
I'm working with Angular Ionic V4, and I installed the Network Information plugin.
On the plugin's "Connected" event - I'm trying to call `this._hubConnection.start()` with the original token. It appears a new connection is established, but every time I get data from the hub, the event runs twice ( or X times depending how many re-connections I've made).

I beleive what's happening is the SignalR creates another socket under the same key, and when a message is sent to the specified key - it is broadcasted to all connections with same key hence duplicates the events.

My question is - Is there a way to "reconnect" to an existing socket instead of "making an additional connection"?

EDIT:

After trying to upgrade to @microsoft/signalr, this is what I got:

[chrome devtool console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRGKZ.png)

It appears it tries to reconnect while the network is offline, and when the network is back it connects and disconnects.

I tried debugging my SignalR server. This is the method that's invoking the events on the client:

```
 public async Task Enqueue(int processId)
    {
        var processEnqueueAppointmentResults = await _processesService.Enqueue<object>(processId);
        await Clients.User($"PROCESS_{processId}").SendAsync("ProcessEnqueued", processEnqueueAppointmentResults);
    }
```

The debugger entered Enqueue once, and on the client - I received 4 duplicate logs (meaning the event was fired 4 times)

Comment: What angular package you are using to signalR?

Comment: @aspnet/signalr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

The problem was that on my Internet connected event I called my `createConnection()` method which initializes the SignalR connection

```
this._hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${this.env.testUrl}/hubs/patients`, {
        accessTokenFactory: () => token
      })
      .build();
```

Instead, just had to invoke the `this._hubConnection.start();` method on my existing hubConnection which solved the duplicate invocation (Just as I thought, every reconnect event added another socket under the same key. When SignalR wanted to invoke the event on the client - it fired the number of times I invoked `createConnection()`)

Comment: where do you get the value for `token` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the old and not maintained package of `@aspnet/signalr` I would recommend to switch to their new package `@microsof/singnalR` that provides the `Automatic Reconnect` feature.

So you can use this feature to SignalR handle the lost connection when it is not an error, just like you example the droped internet connection.

You just add this feature like:

```js
this.hubMessageConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Error).withUrl(signalRUrl + "/yourHub",
      {
        accessTokenFactory: () => token
      })
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();
```

This provably will correct your issue.

Comment: I tried installing the new package instead of the old one. It appears it does try to reconnect, but not successfully. It tried reconnecting in a 3 seconds interval (orso) while my network was down. I restored the network, it connected, but instantly disconnected (without trying to reconnect)

Comment: @YoniZiv hello. Maybe you should try a bigger interval, like 3, 5, 10, 15 seconds?

Comment: @YoniZiv if you want I can provide you an example of how I handle the connection on the front-end...

Answer (score 0):

I hacked together a "safe call convention" - still needs to be more generic, but the idea is that you call a method on the hub - if the connection is down, then a the connection should be brought back up and the method called again. If the connection is down, and won't come back up, keep retying until the connection comes back up and then call the method on the open connection.

```
getChatSubjects(subject?: Subject<ChatSubject[]>) {

    if(!subject) {
      subject = new Subject<ChatSubject[]>();
    }
  
    let connectionState = (this.connection as any)._connectionState;
    console.log("connection state " + connectionState);

    if( connectionState == "Connected" ) {

      this.connection.invoke("GetChatSubjects").then(results => {

        this.chatSubjects = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          this.chatSubjects.push(results[i]);
        }
        subject.next(this.chatSubjects);
      });
    }
    else if(connectionState == "Reconnecting") {
      let message = "Connection in reconnecting state, retrying in 3 seconds";
      console.log(message)
      
      timer(3000).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(time => this.getChatSubjects(subject));
    }
    else {
      console.log("connection in a closed state")
      console.log("trying to open connection again")

      this.startConnecton().then(result => {
        
        if(!result) {
          console.log("could no re-open connection");
          console.log("will retry in 10 seconds");
          timer(10000).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(time => this.getChatSubjects(subject));
        }
        else {
          console.log("connection re-opened")
          timer(1000).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(time => this.getChatSubjects(subject));
        }
      })
    } 
  }
```

...

```
let subject = new Subject<ChatSubject[]>();
    subject.subscribe(results => {
      this.chatSubjects = results;
    })
    this.signalRService.getChatSubjects(subject)
```

Note source code uses RXJS. Also note that I opted not to use the Auto-reconnect feature on the signalR connection, as it's too "happy days" and still allows you to invoke a method on a closed connection.